# Unusual multiple line plots from same data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is crazy - I've read so many "suggestions" and am still stuck, so there is something probably very simple - but...

Data looks like

> head(new_df)
> month   emp year
> 1   Jan 13324 2013
> 2   Feb 13470 2013
> 3   Mar 13740 2013
> 4   Apr 14074 2013
> 5   May 14459 2013
> 6   Jun 14881 2013

The data frame has 120 rows, 10 "emp" for each year 2013 to 2022.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x=month, y=emp, group=1, color=year)) + 
  geom_line()
```

I expected 10 lines, 1 for each year.  I got vertical lines and the 10 years of emp are stacked.
A solution is needed.  Thanks.

This is crazy - I've read so many "suggestions" and am still stuck, so there is something probably very simple - but...

Data looks like

> head(new_df)
> month   emp year
> 1   Jan 13324 2013
> 2   Feb 13470 2013
> 3   Mar 13740 2013
> 4   Apr 14074 2013
> 5   May 14459 2013
> 6   Jun 14881 2013

The data frame has 120 rows, 10 "emp" for each year 2013 to 2022.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x=month, y=emp, group=1, color=year)) + 
  geom_line()
```

I expected 10 lines, 1 for each year.  I got vertical lines and the 10 years of emp are stacked.
A solution is needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want a total of 10 lines, 1 for each year, in your plot. However, your dataframe has multiple rows for each value of year (e.g., six rows for 2013 in the example you provided). Therefore, it sounds like you want to [summarize](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) the data by `month` and `year`, which can be done with the `dplyr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
month <- rep(x = month.abb, times = 10)
emp <- sample(x = 12000:15000, size = 120, replace = TRUE)
year <- rep(2013:2022, times = 12)
new_df <- data.frame(month, emp, year) %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year)) %>% 
  mutate(month = factor(month))

# original plot
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = month, y = emp, group = 1, color = year)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```
# original plot with group changed to `year`, added geom_point
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = month, y = emp, group = year, color = year)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
# summarized plot with geom_point
newer_df <- new_df %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarize(emp_mean = mean(emp))

ggplot(newer_df, aes(x = month, y = emp_mean, group = year, color = year)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: great job!  Very much appreciated.